# Prove the following limit identity $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left( \csc\frac{m}{n+x}-\csc\frac{m}{x}\right)=\frac{n}{m}$

Tags: limits

I am trying to prove the limit I came up with:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\csc\dfrac{m}{n+x}-\csc\dfrac{m}{x}\right)=\dfrac{n}{m}$$

This fact came from the double generalization of the special case $\,m=\pi,\;n=1\,$ which has exceptional connections to the longest length of a $2n$-gon of radius $1$, $\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$ which allows you to prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{x+1}\right)-\csc\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}$$

When I was bored, I began graphing and came up with the above result after a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{Let }\  y = \dfrac{m}{n+x} \text{ and } z =\dfrac{m}{x} $$

$$\text{Now, as }\ x\to \infty\ ,\  y\to0 \text{ and } z\to 0$$

So the limit changes to: 
$$\begin{align} &=\lim_{z,y\to 0} \dfrac{1}{\sin y} - \frac{1}{\sin z} \\  &=\lim_{z,y\to 0}\left( \dfrac{1}{\sin y} - \frac{1}{\sin z}\right)\times\frac{yz}{yz} \\
&=\lim_{z,y\to 0} \dfrac{1}{y} - \frac{1}{z} \\
& = \lim_{x\to \infty } \dfrac{n+x}{m} - \frac{x}{m} \\
&=\frac{n}{m}
\end{align}$$

---

$\rm{NOTE:\ }\lim_{y\to 0}\dfrac{\sin y}{y} = 1$

Comment: I understand perfectly, nice work

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$$

for small $x$

Comment: Not so sound oblivious, but I don't understand quite how this helps, sorry.

Comment: He means taylor expansion i suppose

Comment: Well, yeah I know that. But how exactly does that help my problem?

Comment: $\csc(x)=1/\sin(x)$. Here replace $x$ with $\frac{m}{n+x}$ in the first term and with $m/x$ in the second.  Note as $x\to \infty$ both of the arguments go to $0$.  Now, use the hint.